# Parse Facebook login - Save input username and email

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working on a Facebook login for a Parse App, and have added the login element, but would now like to add the FB profile email and name into the database. However, I am unable to do so. How would I be able to insert the username and email of a new user who is using Facebook to register on the app?

```
$scope.loginFacebook = function() { 

    Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn("email", { 

       success: function(user) {
          if (!user.existed()) { 
             FB.api('/me?fields=name,email', function (response) { 
                 var user = new Parse.User(); 
                 user.set("username", response.username); 
                 user.set("email", response.email);
             }); 

          } else {
             alert("You're logged in with Facebook!")
             //redirect to dashboard page
          }
        },
         error: function(user, error) {
          alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
        }
     });      
};
```

Comment: you haven't called user.save()

Answer (score 2):

Just found out the solution to this. I needed to make a request from FB graphs on the url:

```
$scope.loginFacebook = function() { 

    Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, { 

       success: function(user) {
          if (!user.existed()) { 
            FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,permissions', function (response) { 

              user.set('username', response.name); 
              user.set('email', response.email); 
              user.save(); 

              alert("You're registered and logged with via Facebook!");

              //redirect to dashboard
            }); 


          } else {
             alert("You're logged in with Facebook!"); 
             //redirect to dashboard page
          }
        },
         error: function(user, error) {
          alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
        }
     });      
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you...

```
                FB.api('/me', function (me) {
                    user.set("facebook_id", me.id);
                    user.set("facebook_link", me.link);
                    user.set("firstName", me.first_name);
                    user.set("lastName", me.last_name);
                    user.setEmail(me.email);
                    user.save().then(function () {
                        //go to new page
                    });
                });
```